# How to bind RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint in code using SetBinding?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently, I use this in the `propertyChanged` of the `Progress` property.

```
RelativeLayout.SetWidthConstraint(frameProgress, Constraint.RelativeToParent((rl) => rl.Width * Progress));
```

But I need to bind it in the constructor using `SetBinding`:

```
frameProgress.SetBinding(RelativeLayout.WidthConstraintProperty, ?? )
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is the parent view of `frameProgress` always change? If not, you can directly use the width of the parent view instead of `Constraint.RelativeToParent()`.

Comment: I have added it below take a look

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like:

```
frameProgress.SetBinding(RelativeLayout.WidthConstraintProperty, new Binding(nameof(PropertyName), source: SourceClass));
```

Where `PropertyName` is the name of the property you want to bind with the Width, And `SourceClass` is the object of the xaml.cs/ViewModel depending on where this property is.

Update :

PropertyName would look something like :

```
private Constraint _propertyName;
    public Constraint PropertyName
    {
        get { return _propertyName; }
        set
        {
            _propertyName = value; OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName");
        }
    }
```

And then you will assign it a value like:

```
PropertyName = Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width; });
```

Comment: My problem is how to use `Constraint.RelativeToParent()` in binding

Comment: Umm updating my answer!